# Fixing column "columnname" does not exist pgsql in database. Double quote vs single quote error

Tags: postgresql, insert, double-quotes

I have a table review(movie_id, user_id, reviewtext, date, time, likes, status)/
I get the error

```
column "exist" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO review values ($1, $2, $3,$4,$5 ,0,"exist") ^ )
```

when I want to insert values into a postgresql database. I can not modify the code anymore so is there any way to make this work by altering the database like adding a column?

The code to insert is as follows:

```
 $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO review values (:movieid, :userid, :review,:date,:time ,0,"exist")');
 $result = $query->execute(Array(':movieid' => $movieid, ':userid' => $userid, ':review' => $review, ':date' => $date, ':time' => $time));
```

I understand that a way to fix this is to use single quotes for the column 'status' but the only thing I can do is alter the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

If you had used proper insert - with named columns:

```
insert into review (column1, column2, column3) values (....)
```

then it could be theoretically possible to do by adding column "exist" and a trigger. But this would be **very** far away from being sane solution.

Comment: I tried adding a column "exist" with default value 'exist' but that does not work, since there is no table in the range table to select from. (the target table "review" is not at the RHS in the rangetable, so it appears.

Comment: Next step: a function "exist" with no arguments, returning 'exist'  is not recognised as a function by the parser without trailing parentheses. Calling it by `"exist"()` does give the desired result.

Comment: Well, i said also about adding the trigger.

Comment: As for the second comment - if you can change the source to have additional (), you can also change it to replace " to '.

Comment: Yes, I realised that. But I dont think it is possible to put the idenfier "exist" into scope without changing the query. (it would be possible if Postgres had database-scoped definable constants. Or macros / defines)